# How to make Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 use OpenCL with 7970 card?

Tags: opencl, video-processing, video-encoding, video-editing, amd-gpu

I was never able to make it work, no matter which drivers I used. Now I decided to look into it - if it's possible, I want to make it work, as I'm tired of rendering on the CPU.

Handbrake for example does use GPU acceleration with my card, but in Premiere (since 2014, before then - I don't know because I didn't use it) the setting is just greyed out.

So, how do I make it use OpenCL if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

To use OpenCl with Adobe Premiere CC 2015 you have to use [certain effects](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/effects.html#WSd79b3ca3b623cac9-e423b201260b3b62c9-8000). `OpenCL` is a `Bicubic Scaler`

Check out this documentation article by Adobe on [CUDA, OpenCL, Mercury Playback Engine, and Adobe Premiere Pro](https://blog.adobe.com/creativecloud/cuda-mercury-playback-engine-and-adobe-premiere-pro/)

https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/cuda-mercury-playback-engine-and-adobe-premiere-pro/?segment=dva

The above Adobe Docs page lists the following:

> Here’s a list of things that Premiere Pro CS5 and later can process with CUDA:
>
> - some effects (complete list at the bottom of this post)
> - scaling (details here)
> - deinterlacing
> - blending modes
> - color space conversions

And this:

> The official and up-to-date list of the cards that provide the CUDA/OpenCL processing features is here:
>
> [Adobe Premiere Pro system requirements and supported video cards](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html)
>
> Some of the cards on that list are only enabled if you have the recent
> updates.
>
> If you don’t have one of these cards, you can still use Premiere Pro;
> you just won’t get the advantages of processing with CUDA/OpenCL.